# how to program a lcd screen using nodejs

Tags: node.js, lcd

So I just bought this screen here, [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B073R6SQRY/re](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B073R6SQRY) ... UTF8&psc=1. and I'm trying to understand how to display things on it.

The program will require, at the very least, text to be displayed, but If possible I'd like to display a logo I would draw myself.

As you can see on the amazon page, it has 8 pins: LED, SCK, SDA, A0, RESET, CS, GND, and VCC.

I understand where most of the pins plug into, VCC goes to one of the 5V, GND goes to GND, SCK goes to SCLK/GPIO 11, CS and RESET can be whatever I want. But I'm not sure about A0 and LED.

I also don't know what package I should use to interact with the pins, and that's the biggest issue. the only one I've found is pidriver https://www.npmjs.com/package/pidriver, but the options it has doesn't seem to match the pins on my screen

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Your link to Amazon does not work...

Comment: weird it works on my end, here is another link https://www.amazon.com/dp/B073R6SQRY HiLetgo 1.44" Colorful SPI TFT LCD Display ST7735 128X128 Replace Nokia 5110/3310 LCD @Andrew